# Fourier series question I need help with

Tags: fourier-transform, trigonometry

For the case of $a_n$ I am confused how my notes say we have 1 for the case n = 0. When calculating this integral for sin(nx) when n=0, we should also get zero as at x=0, sin(x) is 0. I must be missing something obvious here. Could anyone explain please?

Additionally, I am fine with $b_n$ but the final solution. How is it achieved? I am guessing that it is some trig identity?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $n=0$ in the integrals and *then* evaluate the integral instead of evaluating the integral first and then setting $n$ to 0.